# Node.js: Postprocessing results of calling recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I need to process objects array with delayed calling external server, collect all results into array and postprocess them. The example is here:

```js
(async () => {
  const serverOperation = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000));
  const myOtherFunction = results => console.log('results', results);
  const objectsArray = [{}, {}, {}];
  const results = [];

  const myFunc = async arr => {
    const el = arr.shift();

    if (!el) {
      // finish of calling recursive function
      return;
    }

    // some big server operation
    const result = await serverOperation();

    results.push(result);

    // need to wait for some time
    setTimeout(async () => {
      console.log(Date.now());
      await myFunc(arr);
    }, 3000);
  };

  await myFunc(objectsArray);
  await myOtherFunction(results);  // <= postprocessing results
})();
```

The problem is: the function `myOtherFunction` is being called before I got all results.

My question is: how can I postprocess all processed results?

Comment: Is there a reason to not just put the call to `myOtherFunction` inside the early return inside `myFunc`?

Comment: Hmm.. Yes, it's not bad option! Will try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a *timeout Promise* which delays the execution of your function instead of `setTimeout`.

The problem with your code is that even if you pass an `async` function to the `setTimeout` it will not stop the execution of your current function. `setTimeout` will just move the task to the microtask queue and execute the function passed to it. But it will not cause your parent function to stop, because the function passed to the `setTimeout` is not called immediately - it's called later, in a different moment in time, in a different place.

```js
(async () => {
  const serverOperation = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('server op'), 2000));
  const myOtherFunction = results => console.log('results', results);
  const objectsArray = [{}, {}, {}];
  const results = [];
  
  // used for delaying operations
  const timeoutPromise = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 3000));

  const myFunc = async arr => {
    const el = arr.shift();

    if (!el) {
      // finish of calling recursive function
      return;
    }

    // some big server operation
    const result = await serverOperation();

    results.push(result);

    // need to wait for some time
    await timeoutPromise();
    
    console.log(Date.now());
    
    await myFunc(arr);
  };

  await myFunc(objectsArray);
  await myOtherFunction(results);  // <= postprocessing results
})();
```

Comment: Yes, I know, how event loop works, thanks. I've just wanted to show the problematic place.

Comment: Sure, I've added the explanation in case someone didn't know that ;)